# Trying to print out points for each word

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a points problem game where each letter equals a certain amount of points and then reads the word in the text file and prints out the total points for each word, but all its doing for me is printing 0, I can't figure out why it is doing so. This is what I have got so far.

```
 File file = new File(fileName);
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        int point = 0;
        switch (point) {
                case 'a':
                    point = 1;
                case 'e':
                    point += 1;
                case 'i':
                    point += 1;
                case 'l':
                    point += 1;
                case 'n':
                    point += 1;
                case 'o':
                    point += 1;
                case 'r':
                    point += 1;
                case 's':
                    point += 1;
                case 't':
                    point += 1;
                case 'u':
                    point += 1;
                case 'd':
                    point += 2;
                case 'g':
                    point += 2;
                case 'b':
                    point += 3;
                case 'c':
                    point += 3;
                case 'm':
                    point += 3;
                case 'p':
                    point += 3;
                case 'f':
                    point += 4;
                case 'h':
                    point += 4;
                case 'v':
                    point += 4;
                case 'w':
                    point += 4;
                case 'y':
                    point += 4;
                case 'k':
                    point += 5;
                case 'j':
                    point += 8;
                case 'x':
                    point += 8;
                case 'q':
                    point += 10;
                case 'z':
                    point += 10;
            }
System.out.println(line + " - Is worth " + point + " Points");
```

Comment: I don't think you want to switch on `point`. Also you're missing `break`s between cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you submitted you are checking the value of the integer point in your switch statement. That does not work because you are essentially saying does this integer have a value of this character at any point. Even if you were to change the switch to the input from the Scanner that is still returning a String and your switch statement is setup for a char.